# Magento2 How to reduce fields from shipping calculate form in cart page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am integrating design in Magento2 and want to remove fields from shipping calculate form like I don't want the country and state. Shipping calculates form should contain only one field i.e zipcode .customer can get shipping rate by entering their postcode.
How can I do this? We have applied all possible ways to remove country and state field. I also tried it by apply javascript for hiding country field and state field but that's also not working because of the knockout loads' template after load whole page.

Answer (score 3):

Hello you can override the block Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor

VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

Please follow below process to hide country and state from estimate shipping form.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
    /**
     * Webkul Grid DI
     *
     * @category    Webkul
     * @package     Webkul_Grid
     * @author      Webkul Software Private Limited
     *
     */
 -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     </type>
        <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor" />
</config>
```

Create VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor.php

```
 <?php
/**
 * Hello Rewrite Product ListProduct Block
 *
 * @category    Magecoder
 * @package     Magecoder_Postnetship
 * @author      Magecoder Software Private Limited
 *
 */
namespace Magecoder\Postnetship\Block\Cart;

class LayoutProcessor extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor
{
/**
 * Process js Layout of block
 *
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function process($jsLayout)
{
    $elements = [
        'city' => [
            'visible' => $this->isCityActive(),
            'formElement' => 'input',
            'label' => __('City'),
            'value' =>  null
        ],
        'country_id' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'label' => __('Country'),
            'options' => $this->countryCollection->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(),
            'value' => null
        ],
        'region_id' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'label' => __('State/Province'),
            'options' => $this->regionCollection->load()->toOptionArray(),
            'value' => null
        ],
        'postcode' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'input',
            'label' => __('Zip/Postal Code'),
            'value' => null
        ]
    ];

    if (isset($jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']
        ['address-fieldsets']['children'])
    ) {
        $fieldSetPointer = &$jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']
        ['children']['address-fieldsets']['children'];
        $fieldSetPointer = $this->merger->merge($elements, 'checkoutProvider', 'shippingAddress', $fieldSetPointer);
        $fieldSetPointer['region_id']['config']['skipValidation'] = true;
    }
    return $jsLayout;
}
```

}
 ?>

From the above elements array you can hide the state and country. To hide it just comment state and country from elements array like this:

```
 public function process($jsLayout)
{
    $elements = [
        'city' => [
            'visible' => $this->isCityActive(),
            'formElement' => 'input',
            'label' => __('City'),
            'value' =>  null
        ],
       /* 'country_id' => [ // Here I am commenting Country and state 
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'label' => __('Country'),
            'options' => $this->countryCollection->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(),
            'value' => null
        ],
        'region_id' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'label' => __('State/Province'),
            'options' => $this->regionCollection->load()->toOptionArray(),
            'value' => null
        ],*/
        'postcode' => [
            'visible' => true,
            'formElement' => 'input',
            'label' => __('Zip/Postal Code'),
            'value' => null
        ]
    ];

    if (isset($jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']
        ['address-fieldsets']['children'])
    ) {
        $fieldSetPointer = &$jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']
        ['children']['address-fieldsets']['children'];
        $fieldSetPointer = $this->merger->merge($elements, 'checkoutProvider', 'shippingAddress', $fieldSetPointer);
        $fieldSetPointer['region_id']['config']['skipValidation'] = true;
    }
    return $jsLayout;
}
```

Comment: This return region.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is_zipcode_optional' of undefined error