# Remove State filed from estimate shipping block on cart index page.

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping, estimate

I Want to remove state filed from Estimate Shipping and Tax block On Cart Index page.

I have Followed [This Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135682/magento2-how-to-reduce-fields-from-shipping-calculate-form-in-cart-page) But Not Worked.

[image]

Thanks